# Linear algebra - Givens rotation when diagonal becomes zero

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, rotations

I'm trying to wrap my head around Given's rotations to generate a QR matrix from an squared A matrix. I understand the general case, but there is a question I can not get out of my head.

Let's imagine for a moment that I have the following matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & B_1 & C_1 \\ 
A_2 & B_2 & C_2 \\ 
A_3 & B_3 & C_3 \end{bmatrix}

But the values of A1 = B1 and A2 = B2, so:
 \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_1 & C_1 \\ 
A_2 & A_2 & C_2 \\ 
A_3 & B_3 & C_3 
\end{bmatrix}

After two steps of Givens rotations I will be left with:

\begin{bmatrix} \tilde{A_1} & \tilde{A_1} & \tilde{C_1} \\ 0 & 0 & \tilde{C_2} \\ 0 & \tilde{B_3} & \tilde{C_3} \end{bmatrix}

The problem is that when I try to make the third step, B2 will be equal to 0, so I won't be able to properly use the given rotation. I understand there are easy ways to patch this (*), but I was wondering if there was any formal way to do it.

(*) The patch would be the following:

> > - If the entire column below the diagonal is 0, then I have already finish and I can move to the next column. In the example above, I simply proceed to column 3. \begin{bmatrix} \tilde{A_1} & \tilde{A_1} & \tilde{C_1} \\ 0 & 0 & \tilde{C_2} \\ 0 & 0 & \tilde{C_3} \end{bmatrix}
> > - If the entire column is not 0, then I can use a permutation matrix and swap the position of the diagonal with a position that it's not 0. A permutation matrix IS orthogonal, so it won't spoil the algorithm, and will not ruin previous columns either.
> >
> > With the example above, the following permutation matriz
> >     \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
> >     Would get you
> >     \begin{bmatrix} \tilde{A_1} & \tilde{A_1} & \tilde{C_1} \\ 0 & \tilde{B_3} & \tilde{C_3} \\ 0 & 0 & \tilde{C_2} \end{bmatrix}

EDIT:

Answer in the comments.

Comment: What prevents you to use the “ordinary” Givens rotation?

Comment: WOW, it may sound silly, I never thought about that. The notes a classmate gave me said the pivots needed to be different from 0, so I never looked into it. An "ordinary" givens rotation with a pivot in 0 is [Ajj = 0, Ajk = 1, Akj = -1, Akk=0 with j<k ], which in it's own way exhanges Ajj and Akj! So I can actually use "traditional" givens without any special patch, the algorithm itself will take care of those cases by itself! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments (thanks algebraic pavel). If the matrix has a pivot in the diagonal, then the Given rotation for that number will be:

\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}

If multiplied by any matriz, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & B \\ C & D\end{bmatrix}

Then the answer will be

\begin{bmatrix} C & D \\ 0 & -B\end{bmatrix}

Which means that the algorithm actually does a row exchange(-ish) for us! There is no need for patches or special cases. If any mod reads this, please close it as solved.